# Beta distribution for pandas.value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, distribution

I have a CSV file containing a 'delta' column/attribute containing the difference in hours between two datetime columns. I am using Python3. When I apply 'value_count()' on it after removing small values, I get the following:

```
delta_filtered['difference'].value_counts()
0    44895
1     8605
2     4624
3     2759
4     1829
5     1449
6     1015
Name: difference, dtype: int64
```

[image: difference distribution]

In the picture, the x-axis contains hours while y-axis is the count. From the looks of it, the visualization suggests that it is a beta distribution. I am now interested in computing pdf and cdf for it using the beta distribution from scipy.

How do I compute the 'a' & 'b' parameters for this distribution needed by scipy.stats.beta() function?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Parameter_estimation

Comment: It doesn't look like beta at all! Looks like discrete distribution to me. I would try Poisson first, geometric, negative binomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can compute the parameters as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
a, b, loc, scale = beta.fit(x)
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit).

However, the beta distribution is only defined between `0` and `1`.

Comment: any suggestion for data > 1? for example, in my case?

Comment: I would try the exponential distribution.

Comment: @DavidM. For discrete distribution, which appears to be the case, exponential is called geometric ;)